# Printing using {fmt} library

Tags: c++, fmt

Can I print an object of the C++ class using [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library?

```
fmt::print("The object is {}.", obj);
```

Comment: An object of what C++ class?

Comment: I think you just need to read [the documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#format-api)!

Comment: Most likely, No.  The `print` function has no idea of the layout of `obj` or how *you* want the `obj` printed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. As suggested in the comments, `fmt` provides support for custom types directly: [Formatting user defined types](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#format-api).

I normally prefer an alternative approach using `std::ostream`. When you implement `operator<<` for `std::ostream` and your custom type, `fmt` will be able to format your custom type provided that you include `<fmt/ostream.h>` as well. For example:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

struct A {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a)
{
  return os << "A!";
}

int main()
{
  fmt::print("{}\n", A{});
  return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that this approach will likely be much slower than the initial suggestion of going through `fmt` directly.

*Update:* To support the claim that using `<fmt/ostream.h>` is slower than going through `fmt` directly, you can use the following benchmark (using Google Benchmark):

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

struct A {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a)
{
  return os << "A!";
}

struct B {};

template<>
struct fmt::formatter<B>
{
  template<typename ParseContext>
  constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx)
  {
    return ctx.begin();
  }

  template<typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const B& b, FormatContext& ctx)
  {
    return format_to(ctx.out(), "B!");
  }
};

static void BM_fmt_ostream(benchmark::State& state)
{
  for (auto _ : state)
  {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(fmt::format("{}", A{}));
  }
}

static void BM_fmt_direct(benchmark::State& state)
{
  for (auto _ : state)
  {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(fmt::format("{}", B{}));
  }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_fmt_direct);
BENCHMARK(BM_fmt_ostream);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
  benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
  return 0;
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
2019-10-29 12:15:57
Running ./fmt
Run on (4 X 3200 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32K (x2)
  L1 Instruction 32K (x2)
  L2 Unified 256K (x2)
  L3 Unified 4096K (x1)
Load Average: 0.53, 0.50, 0.60
***WARNING*** CPU scaling is enabled, the benchmark real time measurements may be noisy and will incur extra overhead.
------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark               Time           CPU Iterations
------------------------------------------------------
BM_fmt_direct          42 ns         42 ns   16756571
BM_fmt_ostream        213 ns        213 ns    3327194
```

Comment: Why will it be "much slower"?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, because it involves iostream which is notoriously slow. I cannot post a link to quick-bench because it does not have fmt installed, I'll update my answer to support that claim.

Comment: Good, that's better

Comment: did you try: std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio

may make a significant difference.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock, it makes no difference because `fmt` does not use standard output streams but in memory streams (I suspect `std::stringstream`, I haven't verified it) which is not affected by `sync_with_stdio`.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. You can do this by providing a `formatter` specialization for your type as described in [Formatting User-defined Types](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#format-api):

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

struct point { double x, y; };

template <> struct fmt::formatter<point> {
  constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context &ctx) { return ctx.begin(); }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const point &p, FormatContext &ctx) const {
    return format_to(ctx.out(), "({:.1f}, {:.1f})", p.x, p.y);
  }
};
```

You can also reuse existing formatters via composition or inheritance in which case you might only need to implement the `format` function.