# Printing a type in a namespace via {fmt} and ostream

Tags: c++, fmt

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597432/647898) mentions how you can include `<fmt/ostream.h>` to have ostream-printable types recognized by {fmt}. I noticed that it doesn't work when the type is in a namespace:

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

namespace foo {
  struct A {};
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo::A& a)
{
  return os << "A!";
}

int main()
{
  fmt::print("{}\n", foo::A{});
}
```

This will result in the old error (before including `#include <fmt/ostream.h>`) for a type without a namespace again:

```
fmt/core.h:1422:3: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'fmt::formattable<foo::A>()' "Cannot format an argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#udt"
  static_assert(
  ^
fmt/core.h:1438:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fmt::detail::check<foo::A>' requested here
  return check<T>(arg_mapper<Context>().map(val));
         ^
fmt/core.h:1587:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fmt::detail::make_arg<true, fmt::basic_format_context<fmt::detail::buffer_appender<char>, char>, fmt::detail::type::custom_type, foo::A, 0>' requested here
        data_{detail::make_arg<
                      ^
fmt/core.h:1626:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'fmt::format_arg_store<fmt::basic_format_context<fmt::detail::buffer_appender<char>, char>, foo::A>::format_arg_store' requested here
  return {args...};
         ^
fmt/core.h:2114:28: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fmt::make_args_checked<foo::A, char [4], char>' requested here
  const auto& vargs = fmt::make_args_checked<Args...>(format_str, args...);
                           ^
main.cpp:15:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fmt::print<char [4], foo::A, char>' requested here
  fmt::print("{}\n", foo::A{});
       ^
```

Is there a way to make it work without implementing `formatter<foo::A>`?

Comment: This is the correct behavior. It's strongly recommended to overload operators where ADL can find them, i.e. normally in the same namespace as one of the operands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), it's required to put the `operator<<` definition inside the `foo` namespace:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

namespace foo {
struct A {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a)
{
  return os << "A!";
}
} // namespace foo

int main()
{
  fmt::print("{}\n", foo::A{});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fmt v8 the code valid, but invalid in fmt v9.
The C++ 20 standard do not support to overload to `std::ostream<<`

API v8 https://fmt.dev/8.1.1/api.html#ostream-api

API latest(v9) https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ostream-api

See also: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/format-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-10/#differences-from-fmt-not-exhaustive

But why C++std not to format by `std::ostream<<`?